# How can I download an app from the Play Store after previously modding an apk of it?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, digital-signature

Previously, I have downloaded a modded version of an app (minion rush, yeah hilarious) and want to be able to download the Google Play Store version afterwards, but instead it gives me an error message which someone has told me it was a signature error.

I've been trying to sign a different APK, that I found off a website, that is the latest original version of the app, and when I go to update it from the Play Store, it shows an error message. This does the same thing when I uninstall the apk and install the version from the Play Store. The message is the same thing that happened before, from when I downloaded the modded version the first time, deleted it, and went to download the Play Store version.

The APK doesn't work without being signed but works fine when it is (btw what I did to sign it was use MT Manager with V1+V2+V3). The only problem is that I can't log into my account on the app and receive my accounts progress.

So, is there any way I can install the app from the Play Store, or a way to allow myself to log into the signed APK?

Comment: Uninstalling an app that is signed by someone should allow you to install the official version that is correctly signed. You just can't update an app from the playstore over an existing app with conflicting signatures and vice versa. If the official version doesn't allow you to login, maybe they banned your account?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. **Short answer: You can't**. Google Play or the developer of the app has signed the app with their private key (which you don't have) and after you've modded the app and resigned it with your own key it has a different signature. This is a safeguard to protect users from installing tampered apps. Imagine someone managed to update your installed and set up banking app with his tampered version. Yikes. The login probably does not work for the same reason with the game's servers denying access because of the different signature.